# Is Ubuntu Compatible with Bluetooth 4.0?

Tags: 12.04, usb, bluetooth, input-devices, devices

I recently purchased a Bluetooth 4.0 adaptor for my laptop. Bluetooth 2.1 was recognised instantly, but Bluetooth 4.0 is not recognised. Is there a fix for this, or is Ubuntu not compatible with Bluetooth 4.0?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu uses the Bluez protocol stack for Bluetooth. From supported protocols we can see what is supported at present:

> Core specification 4.0. Not (yet) 3.0+HS. Includes GAP, L2CAP, RFCOMM and SDP   <sup>[from BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/profiles/)</sup>

So the answer is yes, we do support Bluetooth 4.0. You may want to search for specific bugs or incompatibilites with existing brand-new hardware, or have a look at the [BlueZ development branches](http://www.bluez.org/development/git/) at GIT for more details on future plans, and to find out if your device or a protocol your device needs has issues.